# Silver-promoted reaction of alkyl halide with diphenyl sulfide

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, organosulfur-compounds

What is the major product formed when 1-chloro-3-iodopropane reacts with diphenyl sulfide in the presence of one equivalent of $\ce{AgBF4}$?

[image: Reaction scheme]

I know that sulfur is nucleophilic and that it can displace a halide in a S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction, but the resulting molecule will have a positive charge. Is that okay? What possible use does the product have?

Answer (score 11):

In the presence of $\ce{AgBF4}$, diphenylsulfide is alkylated to 3-chloropropyl diphenylsulfonium tetrafluoroborate. The sulfonium salt is stable and can be isolated as a crystalline product.

[image: alkylation of disulfide]

---

This sufonium salt can be deprotonated (e.g. with $\ce{NaH}$ in $\ce{THF}$) to the corresponding sulfonium ylide.
[image: cyclization]

In the latter, intramolecular displacement of $\ce{Cl-}$ yields cyclopropyl diphenylsulfonium tetrafluoroborate, which again is a stable solid.

This cyclopropyl derivative, once converted to its sulfonium ylide **S** may serve as a reagent in the *Corey–Chaykovsky* reaction.

[image: Corey–Chaykovsky epoxidation]